# How to restrict flutter desktop application on linux to a single instance?

Tags: linux, flutter, desktop, restriction

I am working on flutter desktop app. I want to execute only single instance of the app. But currently it allows me to run more than one instance.

There is [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67233239/run-only-single-instance-of-flutter-desktop-application) for Windows platform, but how to do the same thing in Linux?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/file_lock

Comment: Not exactly. Actually it didn’t prevent a new window to appear, however it was not functional one, the second instance. May be I used the package in a wrong way, it has not detailed description.

Comment: @Anton did you got any luck on it?

Comment: @divyanshingle Unfortunatly I didn’t. But luckily it is not highly prioritized issue for me, so I postponed it for a while. Do you have the same problem or maybe solution?

Comment: @Anton  please find my answer below. It worked for me on flutter 3.10.

Comment: @divyanshingle also thought you might be interested.